# Chrome vs Firefox for images with max-height

Tags: html, css

Take this code and open it in Firefox and in Chrome:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  ;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://curiosidades.batanga.com/sites/curiosidades.batanga.com/files/Los-gatos-nos-ignoran-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

You have to reescale the width of the container by (for example) reescaling the frame or the browser window (this may help: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/NqvYQZ)

You'll see the difference inmediatly: Chrome uses the `max-height` and the `max-width` at the same time for limiting the scale of the picture, while firefox, only uses the `max-height`.

**Does anyone know how to make firefox behave like chrome? Which of the behaviours is the correct one, according to the spec?**

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox specific CSS, witht he code **-moz**
Another solution would be to use hacks
[Browser Hack](http://browserhacks.com/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .selector {
     color:lime;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I've ran this with and without the "!important" CSS declaration and saw a minor improvement for Firefox (and I mean very minor); I did make sure I cleared my history before each run but there could be a few reasons for that. They use different engines so they're going to decide how they should load things differently and when (http://www.quora.com/What-makes-one-web-browser-faster-than-another - an old article but gets the point across).

The link Arjun for Browser Hacks is a good one to help optimize your CSS specific to the browser.